# Jetpack Compose Navigation result being fired multiple times (even with `savedStateHandle?.remove<T>(key)`)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation

I have two screens in my app: SCREEN_A and SCREEN_B

SCREEN_A -> listens for SCREEN_B's result

```
@Composable
fun ScreenA() {
    val result =  currentBackStackEntry
        ?.savedStateHandle
        ?.getLiveData<String>("resultKey")
        ?.observeAsState()

    result?.value?.let {
        Log.d("AABBCCDDEE", "TESTING RESULT")

        currentBackStackEntry
            ?.savedStateHandle
            ?.remove<String>("resultKey")
    }

    // ...
}
```

SCREEN_B -> fires a result and pops itself from the stack

```
@Composable
fun ScreenB() {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        scope.launch {
            delay(3000)
            navController.previousBackStackEntry
                ?.savedStateHandle
                ?.set("resultKey", "TESTING HERE : )")
            navController.popBackStack()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the app navigates back from SCREEN_B to SCREEN_A, the result is being fired twice (the string "TESTING RESULT" is being printed twice).

What can I do to avoid that?

I thought that this piece of code would've been enough

```
currentBackStackEntry
    ?.savedStateHandle
    ?.remove<String>("resultKey")
```

Comment: No sense use `getLiveData`. I also use `remove` within `LaunchedEffect`

Comment: Found any solution for that ?

Answer (score 2):

Better use `getStateFlow` on your result data with `LaunchedEffect`, which suits much more and works proper with Composables .

For example, you can create extension for NavController, to encapsulate logic

```
@Composable
fun <T> NavController.CollectDataResult(key: String, initialValue: T, result: (T) -> Unit) {
    val resultState = currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle
        ?.getStateFlow(key, initialValue)?.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(resultState) {
        resultState?.value?.let {
            result(it)
            currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.remove<T>(key)
        }
    }
}
```